# iOS 11.1 image file

Tags: xcode

У меня xcode 9, обновил IOS до 11.1 и теперь мое приложение не ставится просит iOS 11.1 image file, если у кого-нибудь есть версия xcode 9.1 beta  пожалуйста расшарьте этот файл. Вот инструкция где он находится: только в моем случае будет папочка 11.1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам поможет:

[Image file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2M6nQW14_wpM3BuQlpES3N1X0k)

Из Xcode 9.1 beta 2.